# select Distinct TSQL with totals of distinct

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am looking to make a select statment that selects all the distinct items in a row, and provides the totals of each result

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Column 16] FROM [tab]
```

and thats how far my TSQL goes

Comment: Give us some sample data and a sample result set.

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for

```
SELECT [Column 16], COUNT(*) 
FROM [tab]
GROUP BY [Column 16]
--WITH ROLLUP (if you need to the total )
ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

You can append `DESC` keyword to the end of the query, i.e. `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` if you want your resultset to be ordered in descending order, or `ASC` for ascending (ascending is default, you can omit it).

Comment: OP is looking for Totals.. not Count

Comment: @Raj More: I'm not sure I follow... What is total for a field? It might be a sum, but sum requires argument ( `SUM(some_other_column)`, and I don't see anything in the question about which column to should be added.

Comment: Thank you thats perfect last question how would I order by size of results ?

Comment: @Mike: ` ORDER BY COUNT(*) ` at the end

Comment: Agree with the answer basically (+1), but I think the way you are showing how to use `DESC` or `ASC` may be confusing for those not familiar with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

When you `GROUP BY`, you get a distinct list of [Column 16]. Then you can use an aggregate function with it.

```
SELECT [Column 16], Sum ( [Column To Sum] ) Total_T1
FROM [tab]
Group By [Column 16]
```

If you want to group by multiple columns they should appear in the select and in the GROUP BY

```
SELECT [Column 16], [Column 17], Sum ( [Column To Sum] ) Total_T1
FROM [tab]
Group By [Column 16], [Column 17]
```

You can also specify multiple aggregations (these do not appear in the `group by` clause

```
SELECT [Column 16], [Column 17], 
      Sum ( [Column To Sum] ) Total_T1,
      Count ( [Column To Sum] ) NumOf_T1,
      Avg ( [Column To Sum] ) Avg_T1,
      Min ( [Column To Sum] ) Min_T1,
      Max ( [Column To Sum] ) Max_T1
FROM [tab]
Group By [Column 16], [Column 17]
```